Salesforce Best Practice for handling same members across multiple experience cloud sites
I have a usecase where we have 2 experience cloud sites: 1 for customer portal for lending needs and another one used for mobile publisher one. Now I want to maintain uniqueness of the site members(customers) but the customers may also be same. Please help me with solution to achieve this.

There's no specific programming question here, and it's not clear this is programming-related. This is off-topic as written, as there are no details, and just "Please help me." Please read [ask] and how to write a [mcve]
